# Style is not going to apply to pdf after converting From html string

Tags: asp.net, pdf, itext

I am using the following code. but the style mention in class not going to apply in pdf. Why? What is wrong with this code.

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 30, 65);
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(Server.MapPath("/") + "Temp/" + "parsetest11.pdf", FileMode.Create));
                document.Open();
                string htmlTabel = "<table width='660' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='05' class='myclass'><tr><td>Welcome</td></tr></table>";
                StringReader abc = new StringReader(htmlTabel);
                iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet styles = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet();
                styles.LoadStyle("myclass", "clspdf", "color:red; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; padding:7px; font-weight:bold;");// Not working
                List<iTextSharp.text.IElement> elements = iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(abc, styles);
                foreach (object item in elements)
                {
                    document.Add((IElement)item);
                }
                document.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

iText's CSS support is spotty, but getting better.  Have you tried the latest version: 5.1.1?

Until it's up to the task, I suggest you look at WKHTML2PDF, a command line utility based on WebKit.  Very Nice.

Comment: Hi Mark Storer

 Thanks for your reply.

How can i use WKHTML2PDF in c#?

Comment: I googled "asp command line". The first 3-4 hits all told me how to run a command line application from ASP.  *Try* next time.